# How to listen on another activity's intent data in android native

Tags: android, flutter

I tried to capture a image using a new camera activity, but the result intent of the camera activity always be null in my case. I already implement the onNewIntent listener.

```
public class MyPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware,
        PluginRegistry.ActivityResultListener, PluginRegistry.NewIntentListener {

  @Override
  public void onAttachedToActivity(@NonNull ActivityPluginBinding binding) {
    activity = binding.getActivity();
    binding.addActivityResultListener(this);
    binding.addOnNewIntentListener(this);
  }

  private void launchTakeImageWithCameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File imageFile = createTemporaryWritableImageFile();
    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            activity, "com.example.FileProvider", imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    grantUriPermissions(intent, imageUri);

    try {
      activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID);
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    Log.d("myPlugin", "data is null");
    switch (requestCode) {
      case CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID:
        handleCaptureResult(resultCode, data);
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onNewIntent(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    Log.d("myPlugin", "cannot get the intent data using this method");
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the class instance used?

Answer (score 0):

> the result intent of the camera activity always be null in my case

It is supposed to be `null`. You specified `EXTRA_OUTPUT`; the photo should be saved in that location.